# How do I specify feature columns in Databricks AutoML?

Tags: python, databricks, automl, databricks-automl, feature-lookups

I am running Databricks AutoML in a Python notebook with the look-ups from the feature tables. However, the additional columns are always included, and all runs fail.

```
import databricks.automl

automl_feature_lookups = [
    {
      "table_name":"lakehouse_in_action.favorita_forecasting.oil_10d_lag_ft",
      "lookup_key":"date",
      "feature_names":"lag10_oil_price"
    },
    {
      "table_name":"lakehouse_in_action.favorita_forecasting.store_holidays_ft",
      "lookup_key":["date","store_nbr"]
    },
    {
      "table_name":"lakehouse_in_action.favorita_forecasting.stores_ft",
      "lookup_key":"store_nbr",
      "feature_names":["cluster","store_type"]
    }
]

automl_data = raw_data.filter("date > '2016-12-31'")

summary = databricks.automl.regress(automl_data, 
                                    target_col=label_name,
                                    time_col="date", 
                                    timeout_minutes=60, 
                                    feature_store_lookups=automl_feature_lookups)
```

It turns out that when creating a [training set](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/feature-store/train-models-with-feature-store.html#create-a-training-dataset) you have the option to specify features using `feature_names`. When creating the [dictionary for AutoML](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/automl/train-ml-model-automl-api.html#classification-and-regression-parameters), `feature_names` is not a valid option.

I tried removing `feature_names`, but it did not fix my issue.

I added`exclude_cols=['id','city','state','price_date']`, but according to the error I received columns from feature lookup tables cannot be excluded.

```
InvalidArgumentError: Dataset schema does not contain column with name 'city'. Please pass a valid column name for param: exclude_cols
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing `feature_store_lookups=automl_feature_lookups` produces a successful AutoML experiment, indicating the issue is only in the lookups. The solution is to create a [training set](https://docs.databricks.com/en/machine-learning/feature-store/train-models-with-feature-store.html#create-a-training-dataset), load a dataframe, and execute AutoML that way.

```
model_feature_lookups = [
    FeatureLookup(
      table_name="lakehouse_in_action.favorita_forecasting.oil_10d_lag_ft",
      lookup_key="date",
      feature_names="lag10_oil_price"
    ),
    FeatureLookup(
      table_name="lakehouse_in_action.favorita_forecasting.store_holidays_ft",
      lookup_key=["date","store_nbr"]
    ),
    FeatureLookup(
      table_name="lakehouse_in_action.favorita_forecasting.stores_ft",
      lookup_key="store_nbr",
      feature_names=["cluster","store_type"]
    ),
]

training_set = fe.create_training_set(
    df=raw_data,
    feature_lookups=model_feature_lookups,
    label=label_name,
)
training_df = training_set.load_df()

automl_data = training_df.filter("date > '2016-12-31'")

summary = databricks.automl.regress(automl_data, 
                                    target_col=label_name,
                                    time_col="date",
                                    timeout_minutes=6,
                                    exclude_cols=['id']
                                    )
```

Note: Filtering by date was only to shrink my data and isn't required.